# Placing a Jasper Frame to new Page in Pdf Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am generating a pdf with the help of jasper. My reports contain lets say 6 frames and each frames cover some static text and a table(no of rows in table could vary). Now I want to make sure each frame always starts from a new page. I tried setting different position type but I not able to achieve it. 
Could somebody please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Env setup and release info - Jasper 6.3.0
I am using jasper studio plugin in eclipse and data in table is coming from "JRBeanCollectionDataSource"

Comment: You can use the page break (and Detail bands instead of frames)

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, It worked, I also tried putting them in different detail band which is also one way of doing it